# Swift - Filter array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm having a bit of trouble with filtering an array.

I have this code:

```
var names = [Name]()
var filteredNames = [Name]()

 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == ""{

        inSearchMode = false
        collectionView.reloadData()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {

        inSearchMode = true

        let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        print(lower)

        filteredNames = names.filter({$0.name.range(of: lower) != nil})
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The problem is that it seems not to see letters correctly.
I've printed on the console the name Array, the filetredNames array and the searchBar.text here's the result:

[image: console log]

how is possible that the "Discus" value is not included when typing the d?
it happens with all letters (eg. discus return zero result and so on)

Thank you

Comment: You need to do `lowercased` of your `name` when you do the range comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lowercase both the search text as well as the `name` property when searching for strings using `.range(of:`.

Comment: can't believe it! in the last 2 days have lost my mind on stupid errors... that's not the first! :) thx a lot you've fixed it in 2 mins! :)

Comment: No worries @Marco! Feel free to accept if this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

You have changed the searchText to be lowercase however your datasource (names) contains uppercase letters.

**The Fix**

*Change:*

```
$0.name.range(of: lower)
```

*To:*

```
$0.name.lowercased().range(of: lower)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only searching for the lowercased version of the searchbar input.

You should use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` as the `filter` criteria.

`names.filter{$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchBar.text!)}`

This way you don't have to handle upper/lowercase separately by hand, both will be handled by the function automatically.

Comment: thx! can't believe that in the last 2 days have lost my mind on stupid errors like this! :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)